# Show that $[0,1)$ has no maximum, i.e. $\not \exists \max[0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

> Show that $[0,1)$ has no maximum, i.e. $\not \exists \max[0,1)$

*My Attempted Proof*

Assume $\max[0,1)$ exists and put  $\alpha = \max[0,1)$. Now $\alpha < 1$ else $\alpha \not \in [0,1)$.

Put $\gamma= 1- \epsilon$ where $0 < \epsilon \leq 1$. Then $\gamma > \alpha$ for small enough $\epsilon$ and $\gamma \in [0,1)$. Reaching a contradiction. $\square$

---

First off is my proof correct? If so how rigorous is it?o I'm looking to improve my proof-writing skills and rigor in my proofs so if possible please heavily criticize my proof techniques and proof writing and use of concepts. Any comments and criticism is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can mention that it is an open set hence there exists $\gamma > \alpha$ .

Comment: "for small enough $\epsilon$" How small is small?

Comment: @AspiringMat note he may not have to specify how small $\epsilon$ is by invoking the Archimedean property of the real numbers

Comment: @AspiringMat, see my comment below ervx's answer

Comment: @clark If you use the Archimedean property, why do you need to prove this statement then? You can just quote the theorem without proof.

Comment: @Perturbative I understand what you were trying to do and your intuition is correct. However, I think that if you want to prove this statement, you can either explicitly construct the contradiction number or if you decide to argue like you did then it should be more rigorous than just for some small epsilon. That's just my opinion.

Comment: @AspiringMat The Archimedean property is phrased as in Mejia's answer, so you would have to say why it actually implies the statement, right?

Comment: We can just prove it. Assume that $\mathbb N$ is bounded above. Then there is a least upper bound $r  \in \mathbb R$. Well, then there is some $n> r-1$, otherwise it wouldn't be a least upper bound. But then $r<n+1 \in \mathbb N$, a contradiction. So, $n \in \mathbb N$ can be arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition for the proof is exactly right. To make it perfectly sound, why not explicitly find an element in $[0,1)$ that is greater than $\alpha$. For example, you know that $\alpha<1$. So the midpoint of $\alpha$ and $1$, namely $\beta:=(\alpha+1)/2$ satisfies $\alpha<\beta<1$, which proves that $\alpha$ cannot be the maximum of the set.

Comment: Your proof where you *explicitly* found an element greater than $\alpha$, just **seems a lot cleaner** than my proof where I have to resort to small enough $\epsilon$'s to reach the same conclusion. Is it natural to feel this way about the rigor comparing your proof to the one I posted? Am I right in assuming your proof is more rigorous?

Comment: Basically, yes. Your proof has the right idea, but your argument of take $\epsilon$ really small so that $\alpha<1-\epsilon<1$ is a little vague. The fact that you can do such a thing is basically equivalent to the fact that $[0,1)$ has no maximum.

Answer (score 2):

This is true for the same reason that there is no "smallest positive real number."

It can also be proven same way, namely **the Archimedean property:**

For all $r \in \mathbb  R$, there exists some $n \in \mathbb N$ so that $n>r$. One could proceed directly from the axioms to show this ($\mathbb N$ is not bounded above.)

Either way, the relevant corollary: For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $n \in \mathbb N$ so that $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$.

Now the proof: Suppose that $[0,1)$ has a maximal element $r$. Then there exists some $\frac{1}{n}<1-r$, and hence $r<r+\frac{1}{n}<r+1-r=1$, so $r+\frac{1}{n} \in [0,1)$, contradicting the maximality of $r$.

As an aside, when you are really interested in taking "sufficiently small" epsilons, you can instead defer to sufficiently small $\frac{1}{n}$ and use the Archimedean property in order to make rigorous your argument, and "state" exactly what the number is, since we know it will exist.

Comment: Even in non-standard analysis, there is no smallest positive real number.

Comment: @AndresMejia, could you elaborate a bit on your aside if possible, I'm **exremely interested** in hearing more about how to make more rigorous "sufficiently small" epsilons. I'm currently reading through *principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin* and Rudin makes use of "small $\frac{1}{n}$" all the time in his proofs.

Comment: That's right, my point was only that infinitesimals can be made rigorous, I didn't mean to invoke nonstandard analysis. Either way, you're right.

Comment: @Perturbative the main point is that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$, so the sequence will always be smaller than some choice of epsilon *eventually.*  But these $\epsilon$'s can be replaced by $\frac{1}{n}$ everywhere and you would get the same mathematics. There is nothing special about $1/n$, it is just convenient. Sometimes you will want a different one, For example: if you want to show that some $\sum$ converges, the sequence $\frac{1}{2^n}$ will be more helpful. It depends on what you have seen so far.